# How to shrink 10 digit numeric into 2 character

Tags: sql, oracle, algorithm

I have input comprising five character upper-case English letters  e.g `ABCDE` and  I need to convert this into two character unique ASCII output.
e.g. `ABCDE` and `ZZZZZ` should both give two different outputs

I have converted from `ABCDE` into hex which gives me `4142434445`, but from this can I get to a two character output value I require?

**Example:**
INPUT1 = `ABCDE`
Converted to hex = `4142434445`

INPUT2 = `4142434445`
OUTPUT = ?? Any 2 ASCII Characters

Other examples of INPUT1 =

`BIRAL`
`BRMAL`
`KLAAX`

Comment: atleast show us what you did?

Comment: Add some more sample table data, and also specify the new expected result.

Comment: From ABCDE, what 2 characters do you want?

Comment: @jarlh I have added some more example input data, I want the output to be any 2 character, just so that it is unique so that each I run the function I get the same output for those characters.

Comment: Two different requirements there,  Does it need to be unique, or just 'the same output for the same characters'?  I.e. if ABCDE and ZZZZZ both always gave an output of "Az" would that be a problem?  Do you need this to be case sensitive?

Comment: @JeffUK Yes it needs to be unique

Comment: Do you need it to be case sensitive? Is the input only a-z , or could it be any ascii characters?

Comment: Do you need it to be stored in `CHAR(2 CHARACTER)` or `CHAR(2 BYTE)`? The former will take 2 UTF-8 characters whereas the second will only take 2 ASCII characters or 1 UTF-8 character and there is a huge difference in the amount of data that can be stored between the two.

Comment: the input is always upper case A-Z, output can be any character upper or lower

Comment: This doesn't seem substantially different or improved from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53451265/2226988), which was closed. And, you haven't addressed the issue of impossibility that was raised then.

Answer (score 6):

So you're starting with a 5-digit base-26 number, and you want to squeeze that into some 2-digit scheme with base n?

All possible 1-5 digit base-26 numbers gives you a number space of 26^5 = 11,881,376.

So you want the minimum n where n^2 >= 11,881,376.

Which gives you 3446.

Now it's up to you to go and find a suitable glyph block somewhere in UTF where you can reliably block-out 3446 separate characters to act as your new base/alphabet. And construct a mapping from your 5-char base-26 ABCDE type number onto your 2-char base-3446 wierd-glyph number. Good luck with that.

There's not enough variety in ASCII to do this, since it's only 128 printable characters. Limiting yourself to 2-chars of ASCII means you can only address a number space of 16384.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas Kimber

Comment: This is why uniqueness is a problem.  You can easily solve "Input of XXXXX" must always give the same output",  so that you always convert "XXXXX" into Xy, but you will have a lot of collisions.  I.e. there will be lots of different values of 'XXXXX' which give the same output.    and you cannot find from 'Xy' which 'XXXXX' you entered.